# Android: Overlapping in GridView with TextView items

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview, overlapping

I want to achieve a View (where you see all the notes) similar to the one represented by "Google Keep" - The problem I have is that my notes are overllaping like shown [here](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/vwtvtv/8),
3rd item is overlapping with 1st item.

It is my first app, so if you need sth that could be optimized feel free to speak up.

1.Overlapping - I was trying RecycleView as I think it is used in "Google Keep" but had problems with compatibilit.

When adding dependencies (copied from [lists-cards documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)), I saw some complicated fix for that, but for it to work just like that do we need to wait for google to release new library to support newer versions?

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "radroid.droid_note"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

}
```

FragmentMain.class

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks <Cursor> {

    public static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);



        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

        final String[] mFromColumns = {NoteDbContract.NoteEntry.NOTE_COLUMN};
        final int[] mToLayout = {R.id.text_view_grid_item};

        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.grid_item_main, null, mFromColumns, mToLayout, 0);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_fragment_main);

        gridView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) simpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteDbContract.NoteEntry.NOTE_COLUMN));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditActivity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, note);
                intent.putExtra("row_id", simpleCursorAdapter.getItemId(position));
                intent.putExtra("mod_date", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NoteDbContract.NoteEntry.MOD_DATE_COLUMN)));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        registerForContextMenu(gridView);
        return rootView;
    }
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:orientation="vertical"


              tools:context=".MainActivity">
<GridView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
          android:numColumns="2"
          android:id="@+id/grid_view_fragment_main"
          android:layout_weight = "0.9"
          android:smoothScrollbar="true"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

    >

</GridView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/createNoteButton"
android:text="@string/create_note_button"
android:minHeight="15dp"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="15dp"
android:layout_weight = "0.1"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:elevation="12dp"
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
android:textColor="#455A64"

    />


</LinearLayout>
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:id="@+id/text_view_grid_item"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:text="TEST"
          android:elevation="2dp"
          android:padding="6dp"
          android:maxLines="4"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:maxWidth="200dp"
          android:maxHeight="200dp"

    >

</TextView>
```

3. I also have problem with scrolling I can somhow scroll out of view (all items dissapear and I cant see antthing including button "CREATE NOTE", tried to tackle it but it seems I can't fix it.

Comment: Why `android:layout_height="40dp"` in `<GridView>` ?

Comment: I think that was a experiment trying to fix scrolling. I assume it acts as minHeight if there is layout_weight paremeter

Comment: It seems i fixed scrolling issue somewhere along my expriments. Now I cannot say what was the problem but scrolling works now.